# Register submenu on network menu from the subsite

Tags: multisite, options, sub-menu, add-submenu-page, switch-to-blog

I have a multisite like this:

- MainSite

  - Site1
  - Site2

I want to register `submenu page`

- on active site in parent page `/wp-admin/options-general.php`
- on network in parent page `/network/settings.php`

If I use below code snippet and **activated from MainSite** then it works.

```
add_action( 'network_admin_menu', __CLASS__ . '::menu' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', __CLASS__ . '::menu' );

static public function menu() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'options-general.php',
        'TEST',
        'TEST',
        'delete_users',
        'test-settings',
        __CLASS__ . '::render'
    );
}
```

But, If I activate it from **Site1** or **Site2** then:

- It register menu only on active site parent page `options-general.php`
- **NOT** on network in parent page `/network/settings.php`

I was tried to **Switch to the MainSite** by using [switch_to_blog()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog):

```
add_submenu_page(
    'options-general.php',
    'TEST',
    'TEST',
    'delete_users',
    'test-settings',
    __CLASS__ . '::render'
);

// Switch to the main blog
switch_to_blog( 1 );
    add_submenu_page(
        'options-general.php', // 'options-general.php',
        'TEST',
        'TEST',
        'delete_users',
        'test-settings',
        __CLASS__ . '::render'
    );
restore_current_blog();
```

and

```
add_submenu_page(
    'options-general.php',
    'TEST',
    'TEST',
    'delete_users',
    'test-settings',
    __CLASS__ . '::render'
);

// Switch to the main blog    
switch_to_blog( 1 );
    add_submenu_page(
        'settings.php', // 'settings.php'
        'TEST',
        'TEST',
        'delete_users',
        'test-settings',
        __CLASS__ . '::render'
    );
restore_current_blog();
```

But, Not have any success. Is there any solution?

**EDIT1:**

Is `MainSite` == `Network`?
[Cause, Activated the plugin from `MainSite` it register the menu page on `Network`.]

So, Question is still unsolved! Is there any way to Activate plguin on `Site1` or `Site2` to register the submenu page on `Network`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking a guess here, but my thinking is you are using both the `admin_menu` and `network_admin_menu` hooks to add a menu page with the same slug, causing WP to skip the second call to `add_submenu_page`. I would try creating two separate callback functions (one for network, one for regular admin) with different slugs used in `add_submenu_page` and the use the same rendering callback.